# safari can't execute js on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I want to ask something that I believe you guys know how to solve them,
see the code below:

```
<form method="POST">

            <div class="two columns">
            <label><select name="service" id="service">
            <option value="jne">JNE</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="pos">Pos</option>
            </select></label>
            </div>

            <div class="three columns">
            <label><select name="desprovince" id="desprovince">
            <option selected="selected"> Loading </option>
            </select></label>
            </div> 

            <div class="two columns">
            <label><select name="descity" id="descity" style="width:100% height: 28px;"><option> Loading </option>
            </select></label>
            </div>

            <div class="two columns">
            <label><select name="dessubdistrict" id="dessubdistrict" style="width:100% height: 28px;">
            <option> Loading </option>
            </select></label>
            </div>

    <div class="three columns">
    <a onClick="cekHarga();toggle_visibility('foo')='block';">Choose</a>
    </div>

</form>
```

When I clicked `<a onClick="cekHarga();toggle_visibility('foo')='block';">Choose</a>` other div below should be appear:

```
<div id="foo"  style="display:none;">some query....</div>
```

My question is why safari and all iOS browser can't execute `<a onClick="cekHarga();toggle_visibility('foo')='block';">Choose</a>` while other browser (e.g. Chrome, Firefox) does succeed to executing the onClick event? is there something wrong with safari capability? or they have other terms to execute `<a>` with js command?

or do you think maybe I have wrong with cekHarga function so safari can't execute them? 
here's the checkHarga function:

```
function cekHarga(){
    var destination = $('#dessubdistrict').val();
    var weight = $('#berat').val();
    var courier = $('#service').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'process.php?act=cost',
        data:{destination:destination,weight:weight,courier:courier},
        success:function(response){
            $('#resultsbox').html(response);
        },
        error:function(){
            $('#resultsbox').html('ERROR');
        }
    });
}
```

Sorry if I have odd question or sounds annoying, I'm just newbie person. your answers will be of great help.

Thanks,

Deden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have an outdated version of Safari

http://www.webarnes.ca/2012/04/mobile-safari-bugs-so-far/

Comment: Wow, that was great answer. I've tried with my wife's mac running safari Version 9.0.2! and it works so far!! really appreciate for your answer, thank you very very much.